# Android option menu - multiple items in a single row

Tags: android-layout, android

I'd like to create an options menu which has 5 items total.  However, I'd like to have two items side by side existing in one line and the other 3 can exist on their own separate lines.

Adding the items individually existing on their own line is trivial using .....

But, the question is how to have 2  exist on one line side by side ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a true Options menu (as created by `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`) takes a `menu` resource, which is simply an XML with `item` nodes. If you create a custom menu using a `Dialog` or `PopupWindow`, then you can literally do whatever you want. In that case, create a layout with a vertical `LinearLayout` with some horizontal `LinearLayout`s containing your side-by-side elements interspersed with your regular elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a vertical LinearLayout for the items that exist on their own lines, and a horizontal LinearLayout for the two items that must exist side by side.

In xml, the LinearLayout attribute is `android:orientation="vertical"` or `"horizontal"` depending on which you are using.